# JSON parsing iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am having a problem in parsing JSON url in my iOS application

```
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:MARUTI"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

NSData *stockData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *arrStock = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:stockData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

The link returns an array but I am getting an empty array. Can anyone help please

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Comment: Note: casting an `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` does not make it a mutable array. Instead use `mutable copy`: `NSMutableArray *arrStock = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:stockData options:kNilOptions error:&error] mutableCopy];` Or use an option such as `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` or `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` if they meet the needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned string is not valid JSON because it seems to begin with "// ".

Two things would help with debugging this:

1. When `nil` is returned examine (`NSLog()`) the error return.
   `NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);` returns:

   > error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
2. `NSLog` the returned data.
   `NSLog(@"data : %@", stockData);`

   > data : <0a2f2f20 5b0a7b0a ...
   >   Notice the leading "0a2f2f20".
3. or
   `NSLog(@"data as string: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stockData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

   > data as string:
   >   // [
   >   {
   >   "id": "7152373"
   >   ,"t" : "MARUTI"

Notice the leading "// " which is preceeded with  newline character that is not obvious which is why I prefer the hex representation.

Comment: Amazing Zaph.. You helped me a lot to learn as I'm new to iOS.. Cheers buddy